# How to filter a table using a particular field name in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have table containing data such as name,address,status etc. In the status column, it contains values like Issued or Not Issued which is displayed in a dropdownlist.When I select issued from the dropdown list, it will display Issued in that particular column value. Table is Shown below :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>vb</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>vbbvvb</td>
    <td><select><option>Issued</option><option>Not Issued</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dfddf</td>
    <td>fggffg</td>
    <td><select><option>Issued</option><option>Not Issued</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dddfd</td>
    <td>ghhg</td>
    <td><select><option>Issued</option><option>Not Issued</option></select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the table above, I want to filter all the data according to status column ie. Issued and Not Issued.If I am selecting the value from the dropdown as Issued , then in the table it should show the issued rows only.

The select box is shown below :

```
<select name="status">
   <option value="">All</option>
   <option value="Issued">issued</option>
   <option value="Not Issued">Not issued</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to do this ?

I will show a sample page of my table below.

[Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pllU.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="status" id="statusSearch">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="Issued">issued</option>
  <option value="Not Issued">Not issued</option>
</select>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableId">
    <tr>
      <td>vb</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>Issued</option>
          <option>Not Issued</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>dfddf</td>
      <td>fggffg</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>Issued</option>
          <option selected="">Not Issued</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>dddfd</td>
      <td>ghhg</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>Issued</option>
          <option>Not Issued</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#statusSearch").change(function() {
  searchTable($(this).val(), '#tableId');
});

function searchTable(inputVal, tableId) {
  $(tableId + ' tr').each(function() {
    var allCells = $(this).find('select');
    var found = false;
    if (inputVal == '') {
      found = true;
    } else {
      if ($(allCells).find('option:selected').text() == inputVal) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (found == true) $(this).show();
    else $(this).hide();
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: if that issued and not issued value is inside a select box how to do that ?